# Postgresql - multiple constraint conflict

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I have a table `service` with columns `service_id`, `service_uuid` and `subservice_id`. The combo of `service_id` and `subservice_id` where the column `is_deleted = false` should be unique.
Right, now I have a table with invalid data, where this kind of uniqueness is not in place, for example:

```
id | service_id | service_uuid | subservice_id | is_deleted

1  | 1234       | null         | 75            | false
2  | 1234       | 7777         | 75            | false
```

Because, now when I am doing a batch insert into table I have this kind of constraint:

```
INSERT INTO service (...columns)
values (...values)
  on conflict (service_uuid) do update
```

And this of course is wrong since not all rows have a value for the `service_uuid`.
What I need to check is if the row that has the same `service_id` and the same `subservice_id`  and has `is_deleted = false`, if so it should update that row, otherwise it should create a new one.
So, there should only be one row that looks like this:

```
id | service_id | service_uuid | subservice_id | is_deleted

2  | 1234       | 7777         | 75            | false
```

But, there can be 2 rows that look like this:

```
id | service_id | service_uuid | subservice_id | is_deleted

1  | 1234       | null         | 75            | true
2  | 1234       | 7777         | 75            | false
```

I was thinking of creating some kind of constraint with check, that would check if the `is_deleted = false` and `service_id` and `subservice_id` are unique, but I get a syntax error:

```
alter table service add constraint service_subcustomer_check
    check (is_deleted = false and unique(service_id, subservice_id))
```

Comment: Hi, it would be nice if you could add a data sample and the exact expected result of your SQL statement

Comment: @JimJones I updated the question with more information

Comment: `But, there can be multiple rows that look like this:` <<-- Why? What do these rows *mean* ? BTW: does the table have a Primary Key?

Comment: @wildplasser I am not sure if I get your question? The rows that have ```is_deleted = true``` don't have to be unique. I want to keep track of all the services in my DB, and show to frontend only the ones that have ```is_deleted = false```.  But, only one should have ```is_deleted = false``` where the combo of ```service_id``` and ```subservice_id``` is the same.

Comment: @wildplasser yes, it has a primary key -> id

Comment: That is a *surrogate* key. I've  got the feeling that {service_id, subservice_id} is the *natural* key. You could make that UNIQUE (after getting rid of all the meaningless duplicates)

Comment: @wildplasser I can't make that combo unique, since I will have multiple rows with the same combo {service_id, subservice_id} where ```is_deleted = true``` and because of other reasons that are not relevant maybe to this specific problem, so they will always exist.

Comment: **Why** do they exist? What is their **meaning** ? [in short: what is the meaning of storing the same record *twice*?] This is a data-modelling issue.

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, it is a data-modelling issue that exists from before, but since we can't delete this rows, because other models from different tables are pointing to them I just need to live with that and try to fix that no other duplicates are being created without deleting the old ones, I can only set the ```is_deleted``` to ```true```.

Comment: @wildplasser sorry, I was a bit fast with my question and comments, there can only be one row with same {service_id, subservice_id} where ```is_deleted = true```, but {service_id, subservice_id} can't be a unique key since there can be the same {service_id, subservice_id} with ```is_deleted = false```

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you are after creating a `partial unique index` (see [Create Index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createindex.html):

> When the WHERE clause is present, a partial index is created. A
> partial index is an index that contains entries for only a portion of
> a table, usually a portion that is more useful for indexing than the
> rest of the table. ...  Another possible application is to use WHERE
> with UNIQUE to enforce uniqueness over a subset of a table. See
> Section 11.8 for more discussion.

```
create unique index services_service_subservice_partial_uk
       on services (service_id, subservice_id) 
       where not is_deleted;
```

Since your intent is clearly to maintain the history I would suggest adding effective and end_effective timestamp columns to your date (if not already there). Also as it is necessary to set the current effective entry `is_deleted` before a new one you can create a procedure to do that. Makes it much harder to forget the 2 step process:  See full [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=69103e8b6b5b72c0b53a51ccbe5edbe2))

```
create or replace
procedure supersed_service_uuid (service_id_in    integer
                                , subservice_id_in integer 
                                , service_uuid_in  integer
                                ) 
 language sql 
as $$ 
   update services 
      set is_deleted = true 
    where service_id = service_id_in 
      and subservice_id = subservice_id_in 
      and is_deleted = false;
         
    insert into services (service_id, subservice_id,service_uuid) 
      values (service_id_in, subservice_id_in,service_uuid_in);
$$;
```